Book about alien planet where humans have crashed and now have adapted to the local fauna
This book is about a planet abounding in plant life. There are several levels to the growth and it gets more dangerous the farther down you go. Another spaceship (human) arrives and two of the locals try to stop them. I don't know when it was written but I first read it in the 70's.

This sounds like Alan Dean Foster's Midworld.
Quoting from the plot summary on Wikipedia:

Midworld is a planet entirely covered by a rain forest three-quarters of a kilometer (almost half a mile) tall. Born is a member of the primitive human society that has lived peacefully on Midworld for hundreds of years, careful not to disturb the natural balance of the jungle. His people live in a gigantic tree called the Home Tree. When they die, they are ceremonially buried in another gigantic tree of a species called They-Who-Keep. Each of the locals forms a lifetime bond with a powerful and intelligent photosynthetic animal called a furcot. When they need to damage a plant they are familiar with, they communicate with it empathetically ("emfoling") to make sure it does not object.
The world is disrupted by the arrival of an exploitative business venture from Earth whose representatives know nothing of the delicate stability of the planet. A man and a woman from this company crash in their aircraft near Born's home. He, a fellow hunter named Losting (both hunters are in love with the tribe's most beautiful girl), and their furcots lead the castaways safely through the jungle's surprising dangers to their station.
Born realizes that the newcomers are on his world to gain a life-extending drug from the burls formed by the They-Who-Keep trees around buried people. Horrified by this discovery and the invaders' callousness toward living beings, he uses native plants and animals to destroy their station. In the final fight Losting is killed, but Born returns to the Home Tree. Losting's brain and mind are absorbed to form part of a developing planet-wide network of consciousness involving They-Who-Keep and the furcots.


Now we know where James Cameron got inspiration for 'Avatar'...

@KlausNielsen My thoughts exactly when I first saw Avatar. I was thinking "He must have read Midworld" all throughout that movie.

Yes! that's it! And ditto on the Avatar inspiration.

I've often wondered when ADF will get a co-writing credit for Avatar.
